# UILabel disappears in StackView when there is too much content

Tags: swift, autolayout, stackview

I have a UIStackView with three subviews in it: a title (UILabel), a body (UILabel), and a post image (UIImageView). This last image only gets added when the post has an imageURL (this is optional.)

Looking below, you can see that when I display the image, the UILabel disappears from out of the stackView somehow. How do I fix this?

P.S. Looking ahead, I am going to want to remove imageViews when the user is scrolling from those posts that lack imageViewURLs. Any tips on how to proceed here? Thank you again in advance.

[image]

Below is the relevant code:

```
class FeedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
//MARK: Public properties
var post: Post?{
    didSet{
        guard let post = post else {return}

        // Adding user's name
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: post.author.name + " → " + post.group.name, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)])

        // Adding date and user's first name
        let dateFormatter = PostDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n" + dateFormatter.string(from: post.createdAt), attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(r: 155/255, g: 161/255, b: 171/255)]))

        // Increasing Spacing
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 4
        attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))

        titleLabel.attributedText = attributedText

        // Setting profile image
        iconImageView.setImage(for: post.author, setContentMode: .scaleAspectFit)

        messageTextView.text = post.content

        setupImageSubviews()
    }
}

//MARK: Private implementation
private let iconImageView = CircleImageView(size: 44)

private let titleLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    label.textColor = .black
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

private let messageTextView: UILabel = {
    let labelView = UILabel()
    labelView.numberOfLines = 0
    labelView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    labelView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return labelView
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupDefaultViews()

}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

}

var stackView = UIStackView()

func setupDefaultViews(){
    backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    stackView.addArrangedSubview(titleLabel)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(messageTextView)

    contentView.addSubview(iconImageView)
    contentView.addSubview(stackView)

    iconImageView.anchor(top: contentView.topAnchor, leading: contentView.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 8, bottom: 0, right: 0), size: CGSize(width: 44, height: 44))

    stackView.anchor(top: contentView.topAnchor, leading: iconImageView.trailingAnchor, bottom: contentView.bottomAnchor, trailing: contentView.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8))
    stackView.axis = .vertical
}

private func setupImageSubviews() {

    guard let imageURL = post?.imageURL else {return} // if no image exists, return, preventing image view from taking extra memory and performance to initialize and calculate constraints

    // initialize here instead of globally, so it doesnt take extra memory holding this when no image exists.
    let messageImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        let contentImage = UIImage(systemName: "person.crop.circle.fill")!.withTintColor(.gray).withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        imageView.kf.setImage(with: imageURL, placeholder: contentImage)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()

    stackView.addArrangedSubview(messageImageView)
}}
```

Comment: Use the View Debugger to _see_ what is happening to the views.

Comment: If you are changing the size of a cell ***after*** it has been displayed, you have to tell the table view to update the layout. Either with reloading the row(s), or by calling `performBatchUpdates()`.

Comment: So I managed to fix the issue by changing my approach (using this excellent post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights/18746930#18746930). However, I still have the issue where the images are compressed as shown above, until I start scrolling, at which point the rows resize to fit the content. Would I performBatchUpdates after the images are set in the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so people know how I fixed this, I was attempting to use one cell template which would handle two different kinds of cells. That is a mistake, instead use the information in this `link` [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights/18746930#18746930) to properly create two cell templates. I also found this code guaranteed that the cells were properly displaying the titles:

```
    // Keeps the title text always showing
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()
    layoutIfNeeded()
}
```